# How can I use cordova-plugin-whitelist in a capacitor project?

Tags: cordova-plugins, capacitor, whitelist, capacitor-plugin

I want to use some Cordova-plugins in my project created by a capacitor, a lot of them are easy like the Cordova-plugin-in-app browser and some others. But I don't know how to use Cordova-plugin-whitelist because I can use it by setting the config.xml but there is no config.xml in a capacitor. I have also checked https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/425 ,it seems that I can use the server.allowNavigation instead of using whitelist but I still don't understand how to use it. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You set cordova plug-in configuration parameters via the capacitor.config.ts file. There is a property called cordova.plugins that is used to configure cordova plug-ins.

Look at this documention, at the bottom of the config object: https://capacitorjs.com/docs/config